# What are the current guidelines for performing sensitivity analysis on matched data that is able to compare bias in reference to other covariates?

Tags: causality, matching, sensitivity-analysis

I am trying to perform sensitivity analysis on a causal inference (observational study) problem in a dataset that has a binary outcome and binary treatment. I've applied matching and g-computation with the guidance of vignettes in `MatchIt()`.

I've heard that sensitivity analysis is an important step of the procedure to help communicate the fragility of the assumptions you made regarding your confounders in regards to how it will affect your treatment effect.

I've looked through various articles and documentation that recommend various types of sensitivity analysis, but I'm not familiar enough to understand the what the "current best practices" are.

For instance, Rosenbaum's sensitivity analysis via packages like `rbounds` seem suitable for matched datasets, but the "learning" from these functions is that you learn the magnitude of bias $\Gamma$ required to change your treatment effect estimate, which is difficult to interpret as there isn't a reference point and each causal inference question may differ in tolerance of the magnitude of bias.

I've also seen work such as the one from Cinelli and Hazlett (2020) that is able to show similar measures of bias but includes a reference point to your observed covariates, which sounds more insightful as it is more convincing to say, "even if you had a hidden confounder with the strength of observed covariate A, it would not change the results meaningfully" than giving a seemingly arbitrary value of the magnitude of bias. However, it is unclear if it is suitable for matched data and it does not work for binary outcomes (unless I use a linear probability model via `lm()`, although I'm unclear on how "valid" that is)

In summary, I feel a bit lost and would like to know if there is any guidance on current best practices regarding sensitivity analysis and if there's any readings that I may have missed that would be suitable for my situation.

Comment: I think [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s40471-022-00308-6) does a good job of explaining the current best practices. IMO the problem hasn't been fully solved but we're moving in the right direction (i.e., toward a fully general, method-agnostic method of assessing sensitivity).